# Language not changing in all activities

Tags: java, android, android-preferences

I'm developing and application with multiple activities. One of them is the "Settings" activity, which have an option to change the app language.

Here is how I handle the change language in the Settings activity:

```
final ListPreference language = (ListPreference) findPreference("language");
    language.setSummary(Utils.getStringPreferences(context, "not-found", "language", Utils.USER_PREFS));
    language.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue) {
            if (newValue.toString().equals("English"))
                Utils.setStringPreferences(context, "English", "language", Utils.USER_PREFS);
            else if (newValue.toString().equals("Español"))
                Utils.setStringPreferences(context, "Español", "language", Utils.USER_PREFS);
            analysis_performance.setSummary(newValue.toString());
            restartActivity();
            return false;
        }
    });
```

This is the function that I'm using to change the language, invoked in all activities before "setContentView(R.layout.layout);" method:

```
public static void updateLanguage(Context context) {
    String language = getStringPreferences(context, "not-found", "language", USER_PREFS);
    String country = null;
    if (!"not-found".equals(language)) {
        if ("English".equals(language)) {
            language = "en";
            country = "US";
        } else if ("Español".equals(language)) {
            language = "es";
            country = "ES";
        }
        Locale locale = new Locale(language, country);
        Locale.setDefault(locale);
        Configuration config = new Configuration();
        config.locale = locale;
        context.getResources().updateConfiguration(config, null);
    }
}
```

Apparently it works, but only for some activities. If I want to make all the activities have the same language I have to restart the app after I've used the above function.

This is the navigation between activities:

```
- MainActivity
    - Settings
        - Activity_1
    - Activity_2
```

Activities correctly changed the language: Activity_1 and Activity_2

Activities not changed the language: MainActivity and Settings

The SettingsActivity:

```
Context context;

private AppCompatDelegate mDelegate;

List<String> allLaunchers;
List<String> allLaunchersPackages;
BrowserSpinnerAdapter adapter;

private final String TAG = Settings.class.getSimpleName();

Resources res;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    getDelegate().installViewFactory();
    getDelegate().onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Utils.updateLanguage(this);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings);
    setSupportActionBar((Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar));

    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.settings);

    context = this;
    res = getResources();

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    // Display navigation button
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    final ListPreference browser_selection = (ListPreference) findPreference("browser_analysis");
    fillBrowserSelection();
    browser_selection.setSummary(allLaunchers.get(allLaunchersPackages.indexOf(Utils.getStringPreferences(context, "not-found", "browser", Utils.USER_PREFS))));
    browser_selection.setEntries(allLaunchers.toArray(new CharSequence[allLaunchers.size()]));
    browser_selection.setEntryValues(allLaunchersPackages.toArray(new CharSequence[allLaunchersPackages.size()]));
    browser_selection.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue) {
            Utils.setStringPreferences(context, newValue.toString(), "browser", Utils.USER_PREFS);
            browser_selection.setSummary(allLaunchers.get(allLaunchersPackages.indexOf(newValue.toString())));
            return false;
        }
    });

    final ListPreference security_level = (ListPreference) findPreference("security_level");
    security_level.setSummary(Utils.getIntPreferences(context, -1, "security_level", Utils.USER_PREFS)+"");
    security_level.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue) {
            Utils.setIntPreferences(context, Integer.parseInt(newValue.toString()), "security_level", Utils.USER_PREFS);
            security_level.setSummary(newValue.toString());
            return false;
        }
    });

    final ListPreference analysis_performance = (ListPreference) findPreference("performance");
    analysis_performance.setSummary(Utils.getStringPreferences(context, "not-found", "performance", Utils.USER_PREFS));
    analysis_performance.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue) {
            Utils.setStringPreferences(context, newValue.toString(), "performance", Utils.USER_PREFS);
            analysis_performance.setSummary(newValue.toString());
            return false;
        }
    });

    final ListPreference language = (ListPreference) findPreference("language");
    language.setSummary(Utils.getStringPreferences(context, "not-found", "language", Utils.USER_PREFS));
    language.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue) {
            if (newValue.toString().equals("English"))
                Utils.setStringPreferences(context, "English", "language", Utils.USER_PREFS);
            else if (newValue.toString().equals("Español"))
                Utils.setStringPreferences(context, "Español", "language", Utils.USER_PREFS);
            language.setSummary(newValue.toString());
            Utils.updateLanguage(Settings.this);

            recreate();
            return false;
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

    Log.i(TAG, "onConfigurationChanged");

    getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(newConfig, getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings);
    setTitle(R.string.title_activity_settings);

    // Checks the active language
    if (newConfig.locale == Locale.ENGLISH) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "English", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            onBackPressed();
            return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

public ActionBar getSupportActionBar() {
    return getDelegate().getSupportActionBar();
}

@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getDelegate().onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public void setContentView(@LayoutRes int layoutResID) {
    getDelegate().setContentView(layoutResID);
}

@Override
protected void onPostResume() {
    super.onPostResume();
    getDelegate().onPostResume();
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    getDelegate().onStop();
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    getDelegate().onDestroy();
}

private void setSupportActionBar(@Nullable Toolbar toolbar) {
    getDelegate().setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
}

private AppCompatDelegate getDelegate() {
    if (mDelegate == null) {
        mDelegate = AppCompatDelegate.create(this, null);
    }
    return mDelegate;
}
```

**SOLUTION !!!**

After being in a chat with Rasi we finally solve this by creating this method to fill the layout components, as he recommended in option 1 (option 2 was also a way to solve this but I prefer this way so the user don't have to navigate in the app):

```
private void fillSettings() {

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings);
    setTitle(R.string.title_activity_settings);

    setPreferenceScreen(null);
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.settings);

    context = this;
    res = getResources();

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    // Display navigation button
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    final ListPreference browser_selection = (ListPreference) findPreference("browser_analysis");
    fillBrowserSelection();
    browser_selection.setSummary(allLaunchers.get(allLaunchersPackages.indexOf(Utils.getStringPreferences(context, "not-found", "browser", Utils.USER_PREFS))));
    browser_selection.setEntries(allLaunchers.toArray(new CharSequence[allLaunchers.size()]));
    browser_selection.setEntryValues(allLaunchersPackages.toArray(new CharSequence[allLaunchersPackages.size()]));
    browser_selection.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue) {
            Utils.setStringPreferences(context, newValue.toString(), "browser", Utils.USER_PREFS);
            browser_selection.setSummary(allLaunchers.get(allLaunchersPackages.indexOf(newValue.toString())));
            return false;
        }
    });

    final ListPreference security_level = (ListPreference) findPreference("security_level");
    security_level.setSummary(Utils.getIntPreferences(context, -1, "security_level", Utils.USER_PREFS)+"");
    security_level.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue) {
            Utils.setIntPreferences(context, Integer.parseInt(newValue.toString()), "security_level", Utils.USER_PREFS);
            security_level.setSummary(newValue.toString());
            return false;
        }
    });

    final ListPreference analysis_performance = (ListPreference) findPreference("performance");
    performance = Utils.getStringPreferences(context, "not-found", "performance", Utils.USER_PREFS);
    if (performance.equals(Utils.FOREGROUND)) analysis_performance.setSummary(res.getString(R.string.text_foreground));
    else if (performance.equals(Utils.BACKGROUND)) analysis_performance.setSummary(res.getString(R.string.text_background));
    analysis_performance.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue) {
            if (newValue.equals(res.getString(R.string.text_foreground))) performance = Utils.FOREGROUND;
            else if (newValue.equals(res.getString(R.string.text_background))) performance = Utils.BACKGROUND;
            Utils.setStringPreferences(context, performance, "performance", Utils.USER_PREFS);
            Log.i(TAG, performance);
            analysis_performance.setSummary(newValue.toString());
            return false;
        }
    });

    final ListPreference language = (ListPreference) findPreference("language");
    language.setSummary(Utils.getStringPreferences(context, "not-found", "language", Utils.USER_PREFS));
    language.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue) {
            if (newValue.toString().equals("English"))
                Utils.setStringPreferences(context, "English", "language", Utils.USER_PREFS);
            else if (newValue.toString().equals("Español"))
                Utils.setStringPreferences(context, "Español", "language", Utils.USER_PREFS);
            language.setSummary(newValue.toString());
            updateLanguage(Settings.this);
            fillSettings();
            return false;
        }
    });


}
```

And use it in the "onCreate" like this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    getDelegate().installViewFactory();
    getDelegate().onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    fillSettings();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have write code to change language in a `onCreate()` method. So If you come back to your `MainActivity` and `SettingsActivity` after changing language it won't reflect because `onCreate()` will never call for the activities which are coming from stack. Either you have to take advantage of `onResume()` method of `Activity`.

But still you won't able to see the changed values on UI because View is already drawn on screen. Now you have to two options according to me -

1. Check Locale changed in `onResume()` and redraw view or initialise string resources again. Make sure to call a method directly from an Activity which is changing Locale because `onResume()` will not call of that `Activity`.
2. Move user to the splash screen and launch your App with a new locale. In this case `onCreate()` will work.
3. You can override `onConfigurationChanged()` and check there locale is changed or not. If locale changed then reload new strings.

Comment: "1" option worked for the MainActivity but not for the SettingsActivity, maybe is because MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity while SettingsActivity extends PreferenceActivity? @rasi

Comment: I've tried to implement option 3 but I can't test it because the method "onConfigurationChanged" is never called, I don't know why, I've added the "Settings" activity to the question @rasi

Comment: It is defined as mentioned in the post you linked @rasi